# How to push Ionic CalendarPlugin data to array

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

```
Calendar.findAllEventsInNamedCalendar("Calendar").then(data =>
```

Hello, I am using Eddy Verbruggen's plugin to pull events from an IOS calendar. I want to store these into an array. How would I do so? So far the events from Calendar are coming out but not sure how to store x amount in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the site, the response is something like,

```
{
calendar: "Kalender",
endDate: "2016-06-10 23:59:59",
id: "0F9990EB-05A7-40DB-B082-424A85B59F90",
lastModifiedDate: "2016-06-13 09:14:02",
location: "",
message: "my description",
startDate: "2016-06-10 00:00:00",
title: "myEvent"
}
```

So, this is a common example of a JSON array object.

To access it, you can iterate through the "data" object array.

```
Calendar.findAllEventsInNamedCalendar("Calendar").then(data =>
....
 for(var key in data){
  console.log(data[key]);
 }
```

To access a specific value in that object would be

```
for(var key in data){
 console.log(data[key].id);
}
```

To store it,

```
 var test ;
 test = data;
```

this would then store the data into the test, in which u can iterate through the same as per above.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Gene ! So each of these calendar objects will be stored in a new block in the array. Say I want to know the "endDate" of say the first object in the ID. Would I do "console.log(data[0].endDate);" ?

Comment: @JamesCallyway Yeap!

Comment: any other specific values u wanna get is more for an arraylist manipulation .perhaps iterating through the arraylist and check if the ID matches and etc.